# Django date format swap

Tags: python, django, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a problem with date format. I'm using 'Y-m-d' format. When I enter the format the next time I want to edit, swaps month and day. Reading the doc I see input_format parameter, so I force it `input_formats='%Y-%m-%d'`. And I get an error that the date is not valid.

**forms.py:**

```
date_start = forms.DateField(input_formats='%Y-%m-%d',widget=forms.DateInput(format = '%Y-%m-%d',attrs={'class':'datepicker form-control'}))
```

**template:**

```
<div class="row row-padded">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>
    {{ form.date_start.label }}
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 {%if form.date_start.errors %}has-error{%endif%}">
    {{ form.date_start }}
  </div>
</div>
 <script>
$(function() {
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();  
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker("option", "dateFormat","yy-mm-dd");
});
</script>
```

**models.py:**

```
date_start = models.DateField()
```

**SOLVED:**
No need to force date_format in django. The problem was the picker

**forms.py**

```
date_start = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker form-control'}))
```

**template**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `input_formats` should be a list of formats..

Comment: mariodev, i change it to input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d']. I got no error but still swapping month/day

Answer (score 1):

In your form your [date format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) is `%Y-%m-%d` => `yyyy-mm-dd` which is not equal to the format you set within your date picker script!

Comment: Thore, i use the format 'yy-mm-dd' cause is in the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats). If you put 'yyyy-mm-dd', it puts twice the year.

Comment: The python equal without century is: `%y-%m-%d`