# Correctly exhibiting date from datapicker

Tags: javascript, django

I've created a datapicker to allow user to choose date in a date field. The problem is that I'm cannot change the format date is shown after the user pick date in the calendar. What is shown is MM/DD/YYYY and what I want is YYYY-MM-DD.

I tried already [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37451479/how-to-change-django-date-format-to-dd-mm-yy) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19862519/django-date-format-swap) solution, without success.

**forms.py**

```
project_expiration = forms.DateField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}))
```

**template**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {
            $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                format: 'yy-mm-dd',
                minDate: new Date(),
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the format's property name of a `datepicker` widget is [`dateFormat`, not `format`.](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) It does look like you are using [the correct format](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate), however.

Comment: Yeah it's dateFormat.